# home/xxxxx/public_html/var/view_preprocessed/pub/static/" cannot be used with directory "/home/xxxxx/public_html/var/view_preprocessed/pub/static/"

Tags: magento2.3

I have migrated from from magento 1.9.2.3 to magento 2.3.3.
previously my products in admin panel and frontend was not opening, there was some duplicate entries for product id, so i removed the duplicate entries in the database tables.
Since then the products on frontend started opening but on the admin panel it is giving 500 error, on further checking the logs i found this in exception.log file.

> [2020-01-11 09:04:06] main.CRITICAL: Path
>   "/home/xxxxx/public_html/var/view_preprocessed/pub/static/" cannot be
>   used with directory
>   "/home/xxxxx/public_html/var/view_preprocessed/pub/static/"
>   {"exception":"[object]
>   (Magento\Framework\Exception\ValidatorException(code: 0): Path
>   "/home/xxxxxxxxxx/public_html/var/view_preprocessed/pub/static/"
>   cannot be used with directory
>   "/home/xxxxxxxx/public_html/var/view_preprocessed/pub/static/" at
>   /home/xxxxxx/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Filesystem/Directory/PathValidator.php:63)"}
>   []

I have also deleted the folder `var_preprocessed` and run the `php bin/magento static-content:deploy` many times and cleared the cache but the problem did not resolve.

What can be the issue and how should I resolve this?

Please help..
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to set permission

sudo chmod -R 2775 /var/www/html/var/

Simillar:
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/20639

Comment: Hi ,
I ran this command but now it is saying that CatalogInventory_stock_status is missing from database.

Comment: But it is there in the database

Comment: Can you paste error? Try reindex also.